# addition of the numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array having dimension  500x12 saved in a text file `input.txt`. I want to add other arrays saved in `data` directory having same dimension to the `input.txt` in a loop and want to save it in numpyz format.Moreover, in all numpyz file `inpdata` is same only variation in `final` I wrote the script but it doesn't do the the correct thing as i expected.I hope somebody will help me on this.Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import glob

inpdata=np.loadtxt("input.txt")
otherfiles=glob.glob("/home/code/data/*.txt")

for file in otherfiles:
    d=np.loadtxt(otherfiles)
    final=inpdata+d
    np.savez('files'+str(file),a=inpdata,b=final)
```

Comment: What exactly do you get, and what do you hope to get? (Please add this information to your question)

Comment: Even if you solved the problem, you shouldn't do that. Please add an answer.